# How managed instance groups and datastore / firebase DB are linked?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

How managed instance groups and datastore / firebase DB are linked. Do I have to create separate instance of DS / FB for each instance within a managed instance group or all instances in managed instance group can point to same instance of DS/FB?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want that all the instances will have the same state/data. It's better to create one instance of firebase DB/ DS and point them all to instance to it.